# Kuwait Travel visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, business-travel, kuwait

I am travelling to Kuwait on Business for 2 days, our local partner (from a Kuwait Company) there says I can travel based on a scanned copy of the visa sent to me and that visa stamping would be done on arrival, I am an Indian passport holder and as far as I could check my nationality requires a visa prior to start of the journey, could anyone here help me, I already have a hotel booking and my host (representative of the partner company) says the hotel is the entity issuing the visa, but its sponsored by the partner company.

Would it be safe to travel, I am obviously concerned I may not be granted visa after I have travelled and would like to know if this procedure is normal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your host is correct.

The scanned copy of your visa allows the airline to board you. The actual visa is collected as the visa collection desk at Kuwait airport.

There are two desks - one at the arrivals hall for your meeting party to drop the *original*, and there is one before immigration for you to collect the same paper.

Once you arrive in Kuwait, follow the signs to baggage claim. If you are driven by bus to the terminal (this happens when the gates are fully booked), as soon as you get in the building take a left turn and follow the signs for visa collection.

Give the scanned copy you have and they will stamp your visa.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is enough and more information for me to feel safe

Answer (score 3):

This question has been answered correctly by Burhan Khalid, however I had a strange experience while travelling and thought it would be worth Sharing here.  I had the scanned copy in hand and I reached the airport only to find that the Airline would refuse to board me.

The reason given is that, for Indian travellers, Kuwait airways (and a few other airlines) are taking extra precaution and has devised a system whereby on deposit of original visa at the airport, a message is sent to the Indian airport and only if there is such a confirmation, the passenger is allowed to travel.  Apparently this system is created to avoid unscrupulous agents who send people with just a scanned (fake) copy of a made up visa which resulted earlier in many people who had to be deported upon arrival in Kuwait.

[Here](http://www.airindia.in/visa-on-arrival-for-gulf-countries.htm) is a link to the rule being shown in Air India website.

In my case the partner had not deposited the original till about 1 hour prior to my arrival and hence it was an extremely bad situation, I however managed to travel with personal guarantee from a few airline staff at Kuwait end, but this is a special situation for Indians travelling to Kuwait (not sure of other places).

So prior to your travel, please ensure that visa is deposited well in advance and that the airline sends a message to your port of departure.

Comment: @JoErNanO Added Air-India website link though the airline is different its the same rule being enforced

Comment: This is called _boarding authorization_ sometimes called `OK TO BOARD` and it is a requirement where the visa is electronic and/or its stamped at the immigration counter. There are similar restrictions for Pakistani citizens traveling to Dubai - but this is a fairly new procedure.